# Filtering scanned MAC address and display in textbox or listbox without duplication

Tags: c#, serial-port, mac-address, serial-communication

[Tool Image Winform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUtI6.png)
I am working on a tool that connected to my Bluetooth receiver and scan and get MAC address of BLE devices. So far I can scan and have the mac address continuously display in textbox. I am having problem with filtering MAC address?(Our assigned MAC address 88 99 66 55 4X XX the last 12 bit is free to use). How can I filter this while scanning and put it in Listbox or Textbox for later use.

```
    public SerialPort serialport;
    private bool buttonWasClicked = false;



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        foreach (string s in SerialPort.GetPortNames())
        {
            cmPort.Items.Add(s);
        }




    }


    public void serialport_connect(String port, int baudrate)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();


        serialport = new SerialPort(port, baudrate);


        try
        {
            serialport.Open();


            textBox1.AppendText(" OPEN " + "[" + dtn + "] " + " Port Opened: Connected\n");


            // Event Handler
            serialport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(port_DataReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error");
        }
    }




    private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {



        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();
        //TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
        if (buttonWasClicked == true)
        {
            ThreadSafeDelegate(delegate { ScanList.Items.Add(serialport.ReadExisting()); });
            //ThreadSafeDelegate(delegate { textBox3.Text += "\r\n"; });
        }
        else
        {
            ThreadSafeDelegate(delegate { textBox1.AppendText(serialport.ReadExisting()); });
            ThreadSafeDelegate(delegate { textBox1.Text += "\r\n"; });
            //textBox1.AppendText(serialport.ReadExisting());
            //textBox1.Text += "\r\n";
        }



    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        byte[] msg = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(textBox2.Text + "\0");


        serialport.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);           



    }


    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String port = cmPort.Text;
        int baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(cmBaud.Text);
        //Parity parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cmbparity.Text);
        //int databits = Convert.ToInt32(cmbdatabits.Text);
        //StopBits stopbits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cmbstopbits.Text);
        button3.Enabled = true;
        serialport_connect(port, baudrate);


    }


    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();


        if (serialport.IsOpen)
        {
            serialport.Close();
            button3.Enabled = false;
            button2.Enabled = true;
            textBox1.AppendText("[" + dtn + "] " + "Port Close: Disconnected\n");
        }
    }

    private void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = "";
    }


    private void ThreadSafeDelegate(MethodInvoker method)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
            BeginInvoke(method);
        else
            method.Invoke();
    }


    private void Scan_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        buttonWasClicked = true;


        byte[] msg = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes( "SNS10" + "\0");


        serialport.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What exacly do you mean by `filtering MAC address`? What is your current problem? Why is the format / leading bits important to your question?

Comment: Filtering Mac address: We are assigned to specific MAC address which I wrote above and while scanning I only want to show the devices which has this address the other bluetooth device should be filtered in winfoms. So as you can see in the scan list we have address that we dont want and I want to filter in this list only our MAC address without duplication.

Comment: I have added the Image in original post  as Tool Image Waveforms

Comment: Let me rephrase it: How can I create a filter in textbox ro listbox so that data receiving from serial port only show messages start from:                   
 VNR88-99-66-55-4?                                                                                         
 I hope this is clear